# Show all rows without tabs in RMarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

If I output a data.frame in RMarkdown, the resulting HTML will only show 10 rows at a time.

How do I keep the nice formatting but show all rows?

For example if I want to output all rows of `mtcars`:

[image]

Comment: Looks like you already got your answer, but another thing I learned is that there is an HTML document argument in the YAML called "df_print" which can be used at times to help render HTML tables easily

Comment: Thanks, but there doesn't appear to be any setting for max.rows available from the YAML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep the same formatting but drop the tabs/paging, use the following:

````
```{r results='asis'}

knitr::kable(mtcars)  

`` `
````

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by setting the options pageLength of DT:
Example rmd:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "TarJae"
date: "5 2 2021"
output: html_document
---
```

chunk 1

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(DT)
options(DT.options = list(pageLength = 100, language = list(search = 'Filter:')))
```

chunk 2:

```
datatable(mtcars)
```

Comment: This gives a similar table in the knitted document, but not the same. What method is actually used for printing when you simply say `mtcars` in your notebook and knit to HTML?